# How to merge sorted sequence with different size?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I am looking for an algorithm to merge multiple sorted sequences, lets say X sorted sequences, into one sorted sequence in c, can you provide some examples?

Note that each sequence has different size.

I thought of this but sequences might have overlapping intervals. so it won't work.

```
x=s1[first] 
y=s2[last]
if(x<y) then put s1 after s2 in the output.
...
```

note: I do not want to use any library

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: What do you mean by "sequences might have overlapping intervals?"

Comment: Why the C++ tag if you want a C solution?

Comment: @jschultz410 e.g. s1:{100,200} s2: {150, 151}. combined 150,151,100,200

Comment: Don't you mean combined: { 100, 150, 151, 200 } ???

Comment: @jschultz410 i meant the result according to my first attempt. the output you wrote is my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge your input sequences like a N-way [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) does.

Basically, you examine the head of each of your ordered input sequences and append the minimal head to your new ordered sequence (and update the head of the sequence from which you consumed).  You do that until all of your input sequences are empty.

If you have a significant number of input sequences to merge, then you may want to maintain a min-heap of the heads of your input sequences rather than doing a linear scan for the minimal head each time.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct
{
  size_t size;
  int   *seq;

} Sequence;

Sequence *mergeSortedSequences(const Sequence *seqs[], size_t num_seqs)
{
  Sequence *ret = malloc(sizeof(Sequence));
  size_t    indexes[num_seqs];  /* NOTE: not valid C89; in C89 need to malloc instead or have seqs be non-const and trash the Sequences themselves */
  size_t    tot_size;
  size_t    i;

  if (NULL == ret)
    goto FAIL;

  ret->size = 0;

  /* calculate total size of merged Sequence, init indexes and cull any empty sequences from seqs */

  for (i = 0, tot_size = 0; i < num_seqs;)
  {
    if (0 != seqs[i]->size)
    {
      tot_size += seqs[i]->size;
      indexes[i] = 0;
      ++i;
    }
    else
    {
      seqs[i] = seqs[--num_seqs];  /* cull empty seq from seqs */
      printf("Swapping original seq %lu into position %lu\n", num_seqs, i);
    }
  }

  printf("Return sequence size is %lu; number of non-empty sequences: %lu\n", tot_size, num_seqs);

  ret->seq = calloc(tot_size + 1, sizeof(int));  /* NOTE: +1 so we don't ever calloc(0) */

  if (NULL == ret->seq)
    goto FAIL_RET;

  /* loop while non-empty sequences left */

  while (num_seqs)
  {
    /* find minimum of remaining seqs */

    int    min     = seqs[0]->seq[indexes[0]];
    size_t min_seq = 0;

    for (i = 1; i < num_seqs; ++i)
    {
      if (seqs[i]->seq[indexes[i]] < min)
      {
        min     = seqs[i]->seq[indexes[i]];
        min_seq = i;
      }
    }

    /* update ret */

    ret->seq[ret->size++] = min;

    printf("minimum value was from head of seq %lu; ret[%lu] = %d\n", min_seq, ret->size, min);

    /* update indexes, min_seq and seqs */

    ++indexes[min_seq];  /* "consume" the head of min_seq */

    if (indexes[min_seq] == seqs[min_seq]->size)  /* we've exhausted min_seq */
    {
      seqs[min_seq]    = seqs[--num_seqs];        /* cull empty sequence */
      indexes[min_seq] = indexes[num_seqs];
      printf("Swapping seq %lu into position %lu (2)\n", num_seqs, min_seq);
    }
  }

  printf("Success ret->size = %lu\n", ret->size);

  assert(NULL != ret && ret->size == tot_size);
  goto END;

  /* error handling and return */

FAIL_RET:
  free(ret);
  ret = NULL;

FAIL:
  assert(NULL == ret);

END:
  return ret;  
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int       arr1[] = { -44, 0, 22, 49, 58, 101 };
  int       arr3[] = { -101, 14, 22, 31, 151 };
  int       arr4[] = { -1, 0, 1, 50, 200 };
  Sequence  seq0   = { 0, NULL };
  Sequence  seq1   = { sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(arr1[0]) };
  Sequence  seq2   = { 0, NULL };
  Sequence  seq3   = { sizeof(arr3) / sizeof(arr3[0]) };
  Sequence  seq4   = { sizeof(arr4) / sizeof(arr4[0]) };
  Sequence  seq5   = { 0, NULL };
  Sequence *seqs[6];
  Sequence *ret;
  size_t    i;

  seq1.seq = arr1;
  seq3.seq = arr3;
  seq4.seq = arr4;

  seqs[0] = &seq0;
  seqs[1] = &seq1;
  seqs[2] = &seq2;
  seqs[3] = &seq3;
  seqs[4] = &seq4;
  seqs[5] = &seq5;

  ret = mergeSortedSequences((const Sequence**) seqs, sizeof(seqs) / sizeof(seqs[0]));

  if (NULL == ret)
  {
    perror("Allocation failure!");
    abort();
  }

  printf("Merged sequence contains %lu elements:\n", ret->size);

  for (i = 0; i < ret->size; ++i)
    printf("\t%d\n", ret->seq[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to have time to give a code example? I'm not good with basic algorithms and i need to solve the problem by tomorrow morning.

Comment: There you go.  You might not want to try to pass that off as your work though.

Comment: Please don't give verbatim solutions to homework problems.  It doesn't help anyone in the long-run, and only encourages laziness.

Comment: I can't possibly copy paste (or similar) this and I have to use pipes with multiple processes. Thank you very much jsc.